# Put a SQL result value in a dropdownlist vba access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to put a value in a dropdownlist with Access but I can't... Here is my code :

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL1 As String
Dim resultat As String

SQL1 = "SELECT Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi.Num_EB FROM Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi WHERE Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi.Code_projet = " & "'" & CodeProjet1.Value & "'"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL1, dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
resultat = rst(0)
Me.NumEB1.Value = resultat

rst.Close
```

"NumEB1" is my dropdownlist

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What's happening/error?  you can use dlookup to get 1 value like this.

Comment: Why not simply add the sql as the recordsource for the dropdown?

Comment: Because I want to change the value of "NumEB1" after an update of an another DropDownlist. The code is in "CodeProjet1_AfterUpdate()" --> CodeProjet1 is a dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
> Dim SQL1 As String
> 
> 
> SQL1 = "SELECT Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi.Num_EB FROM
> Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi WHERE
> Table_de_correspondance_Galiléi.Code_projet = " & "'" &
> CodeProjet1.Value & "'"
> 
> Me.NumEB1.RecordSource = SQL1
```